# Creating a 'new line' class to bind to return key

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, keyboard-events, tkinter-canvas

I'm fairly new to python and have been trying to create a program, using tkinter, which allows a user to type text directly onto a canvas. I have managed to do this, albeit probably not in the most efficient way. The problem I am having is trying to bind the return key in order for the user to take a new line if they wish. I have searched up tutorials in order to help with this [1](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#canvas.Canvas.index-method) but nothing has worked so far. Here is the code I have so far.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

c = Canvas(root)
c.pack()
textvar = StringVar()
t = c.create_text(100, 100, text='Press Ctrl E to enter text', anchor='nw',width=140)

def edit_begin(event):
    x, y = c.coords(t)
    textvar.set(c.itemcget(t, 'text'))
    e = Entry(c, width= 25, textvariable=textvar, bd=0,
                highlightthickness=0, bg=c['bg'])
    e.selection_range(0, 'end')
    w = c.create_window(x, y, window=e, tags=('editwindow',), anchor='nw')
    e.focus_set()
    e.bind('<1>', edit_end)
    e.bind('<Escape>', edit_cancel)
    e.bind('<Return>', edit_n)

def edit_cancel(event):
    c.delete('editwindow')
    event.widget.destroy()
    c.focus_set()

def edit_end(event):
    c.itemconfigure(t, text=textvar.get())
    edit_cancel(event)

def edit_n(event):
    c.insert(t, END, "\n")

c.bind('<Control-e>', edit_begin)

c.focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```

Not only is the return key not allowing a new line to be entered, but it is also not showing up with any errors, which doesn't help with trying to figure out how to fix this.

Any help with the main problem of allowing the return key to enter a new line, and/or any comments on how to improve the general layout of the code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Entry widgets are single-line only. You can use a text widget, or you can use the canvas text item.

http://effbot.org/zone/editing-canvas-text-items.htm